# Spring Boot, Docker, Discovery eureka

Tags: docker, spring-boot, amazon-ecs, netflix-eureka, discovery

I have the following problem.

I have two Springboot services: Service A and Service Discovery Eureka.

And I have two use cases.

1. I want to start they localy
2. I would like to start they in aws ECS.

I packed they in the container. And i start the Service A with the random docker port mapping: `docker run -p 0: 8080 serviceA`

And after that I have the following problem.

> Docker Service A registers with docker discovery services with an
>   incorrect port. Service A registers with the port of Spring Boot
>   Application 8080, not the docker port.

How can I tell Service A to register with the port of docker?

Answer (score 0):

Eureka will try to invoke your service in the port defined in the `boostrap.yml` file or 8080 if none is defined.
Therefore, you will need to open data same port mapping in your Docker container:

```
docker run -p 8080:[the port used your application]
```

Keep in mind that reading the bootstrap file is the first thing done by Spring at startup.

In case you want to run locally, you can define a profile where Spring Cloud is disabled and the port usage is the typical one (i.e. defined by the property server.port)